# Centering Map around multiple points (annotations) on the map - Titanium mobile

Tags: titanium, region

I have multiple annotations on the map - although the user may need to scroll to see them. I want the user to be able to select a button to fit them all on the map - eliminating the need to scroll/manually resize.

I have determined the min. and max. latitudes and longitudes (e.g minLat, maxLat, minLong, maxLong) for the points I want to show on the map.

I'm struggling, however, with the specific formula to use to get the longitude and latitude properties to pass to mapview.setLocation. Any pointers on what formula I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have made a function for the same requirement. You can test and let me know if it gives some error:

```
function setMarkersWithCenter(map,latiarray,longiarray)
{
    if(latiarray.length != longiarray.length)
        return;
    var total_locations = latiarray.length;
    var minLongi = null, minLati = null, maxLongi = null, maxLati = null;
    var totalLongi = 0.0, totalLati = 0.0;

    for(var i = 0; i < total_locations; i++) 
    {
        if(minLati == null || minLati > latiarray[i]) {
            minLati = latiarray[i];
        }
        if(minLongi == null || minLongi > longiarray[i]) {
            minLongi = longiarray[i];
        }
        if(maxLati == null || maxLati < latiarray[i]) {
            maxLati = latiarray[i];
        }
        if(maxLongi == null || maxLongi < longiarray[i]) {
            maxLongi = longiarray[i];
        }
    }

    var ltDiff = maxLati-minLati;
    var lgDiff = maxLongi-minLongi;
    var delta = ltDiff>lgDiff ? ltDiff : lgDiff;
    if(total_locations>0 && delta>0)
    {
        map.setLocation({
            animate : true,
            latitude:((maxLati+minLati)/2),
            longitude:((maxLongi+minLongi)/2),
            latitudeDelta:delta,
            longitudeDelta:delta,
        }); 
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @DhairyaVora your code works really nice. I was to use it in my app. However, when annotations are separated with greater distance (e.g. on different continents it throws an error. Something like:

"Invalid Region <center:+44.76096565, -23.38837147 span:+156.84360058, +438.7500"

My guess: it has something to do with Earth being round :)

Is there a way to adjust your formula a bit to accomodate very large distances or at least focus on the larger group of annotations (or maybe just the first on the list) if something like this happens?

Comment: @kernelpanic, that is a good idea. We can put this code in try catch and if some error occurs, catch can show first annotation. And by the way, can you show me example locations for which this error occurs?

Comment: @DhairyaVora I'm glad you're open to some improvements. In my example the error is thrown when I have two annotations - one in Atlanta, USA and another in Switzerland

Comment: I could not find any error. As per the locations given by you, I have taken: 33.749,-84.387982 AND 47.051411,8.315826. Above code is running fine with me. Function sets center point at 40.4002055,-38.0360779

Comment: this is a fantastic question and brilliant answer.  Did you mange to resolve/repeat the issue described by kernelpanic?  It the function good in its current form?

Comment: This function working fine for me so far. I have not found any bug till now. If you find some bug, let me know; I can try to update the function.